# Remove last two digits of filename

Tags: php, string, filenames

How can I remove the last two characters of a filename in PHP?

```
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/tsra50.jpg
# becomes
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/tsra.jpg
```

and

```
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/hi_shwrs60.jpg
# becomes
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/hi_shwrs.jpg
```

The extension will always be 3 characters (4 with the period).

Comment: Possibly related by same user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738084/find-if-last-two-characters-in-filename-are-numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative value as start to `substr_replace` if you know that the number always is two digits:

```
$filename = 'filename11.jpg';
$newfilename = substr_replace($data, '', -6, 2);
```

Comment: This worked: `substr_replace($filename, '', -6, 2);`. The extension thing was not needed.

Comment: @DaAwesomeP - I didn't test it, but I'll update my answer then.