# Find if last two characters in filename are numbers

Tags: php, filenames

I want to see if the last two characters/digits in a filename are numbers in PHP.

```
if (CODE HERE) {
 // runs script because last two characters are numbers
}
```

This should set it off:

```
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/hi_shwrs20.jpg
The last two digits are '20'
```

This should not:

```
http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/skc.jpg
There are no last two digits
```

Comment: I like the CODE HERE part

Comment: I haven't tried anything - I have no clue. I think I may be able to find it by detecting the two characters before the period or just the two characters before the last four.

Comment: Looks like you're using [so] to build your code line by line: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19737927

Comment: @b__, I really am not. I'm building a very complicated forecast data and weather station center with graphs, tables, sorting, and manipulation. I didn't want to combine them into one question because then when a developer searches "remove last two digits of filename php" he can have a result. It helps the community.

Comment: You're basically going down this road: http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: I can see your point about the downvotes. I can't delete the posts or that will surely get me banned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<?php
    $filename = "http://www.nws.noaa.gov/weather/images/fcicons/skc23.jpg";
    $posOfPeriod = strrpos($filename, ".");
    $last2digits = substr($filename, $posOfPeriod -2, 2);
    if (is_numeric($last2digits)) {
        echo "Numeric: ".$last2digits;
    }
    else {
        echo "Non-Numeric: ".$last2digits;
    }
?>
```

Comment: That finds it alright, but how can I see if they are **both** numbers or just other text?

Comment: This worked: `if(is_numeric(substr($day->getIcon(), -6, 2))) {}`. I don't know why you changed your original answer.

Comment: @DaAwesomeP, The latest code is the one you seek.

Comment: Thanks! I see that this one detects the period, not the extension so that it will work with a four or two character extension. I shortened it (I'm not interested in seeing what the digits are) `if (is_numeric(substr($filename, strrpos($filename, ".") -2, 2))) { //is numeric }`.